# Azure DocumentClient initialization throws System.TypeLoad Exception

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, visual-studio-mac

**Update (Latest):**
Issue resolved.  There's nothing wrong with my code.  The error is thrown by System.Mono.  I was able to run my app after moving my project to a windows machine.

Note: MS.Azure.DocumentDB (v1.14) is built on top of NewtonJson 6.0.0.0.  Although it says in Nuget that NewtonJson version >= 6.0.8 would work, I had the latest v10.0.0.0 and it threw an exception.  So make sure you build with NewtonJson 6.

**Update:**

**I downloaded the sample right from Azure portal under quick start.  I get the exact same error as the one from my own project.  I think something is wrong with VS for Mac (mono framework).  Exact error message:
[My exact exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pkiU.png)
BTW, about the image, I really have a hard time adding the image.  The image popup keeps giving me an error after I drag or select a pic to upload.  I have no choice but to put up the link.**

I am using a Visual Studio on Mac trying to connect to my Azure DocumentDB on the cloud (Not emulator).  I really have no idea why I keep getting this error.  I've checked the System.Core and it was using the 4.0.0.0 version, and also tried deleting the core and added it back in.  I also tried deleting the MS.Azure.DocumentDB client and added it back in.  I am now suspecting that the DocumentDB API is built with a different version of System.Core.  Can someone please help me with this?

```
        try
        {
            _client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"])
                                     , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);

            CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        }
        catch(DocumentClientException de)
        {
            Exception baseException = de.GetBaseException();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Exception baseException = e.GetBaseException(); 
            string message = e.Message;
        }
```

Below is the exception

> "Could not resolve type with token 010000f6 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventProviderTraceListener, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)"

Trace Type:
"System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventProviderTraceListener"

Comment: What's the point of lying about this?  I was trying to show people at what line it failed and the exact error message.  Not sure why you think there's a problem.  The dialog is in the image.  I've tried to do copy and paste into the edit box but somehow it wouldn't let me.  Maybe I don't have enough points...

Comment: If you specify to include more output when building (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx) are there any warnings that may shed some more light on the issue?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your suggestion.  I use VS for mac.  Unfortunately, I don't see any of those options available for VS mac version.  I checked several places and I don't see anywhere I can set those things.  In addition, my output is to bin and I see no text files at all in the bin folder.  Clueless at this point.